# htmlentities and french characters

Tags: php

I am trying to escape some users input in form.

```
if( !empty($_SESSION['descr']) )
{
    $descr = htmlentities($_SESSION['descr']);
    $descr = stripslashes($descr);
    $descr = html_entity_decode($descr); 

    echo"<textarea cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" name=\"descr\" >".$descr."</textarea>";
}
else
{
    echo "<textarea cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\" name=\"descr\" ></textarea>";
}
```

I didn't use html_entity_decode() in the first place then I realized if a user put some French characters then it won't show them correctly. 
Is it save to use it the way it is with html_entity_decode()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the encoding of the string to ISO-8859-15, which picks up characters that LATIN-1 misses (ie french characters):

```
$descr = htmlentities($desc,ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-15');
```

ENT_COMPAT may not be the flag you are looking for, but you can find a subtitle in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: I would recommend `UTF-8` instead of `ISO-8859-15`. What if a user puts Greek, or Russian, or Hebrew characters? Recommending anything other than UTF-8 is unwise today.

Comment: Agreed, the only other option that i can think of is using a string replace of a list of characters vs hexadecimal array, which is tedious.